# HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'. Ошибка при загрузке xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, csrf

При загрузке xml файла выдает ошибку - HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.
Добавил функцию.

petit.jsp

```
<br>

 <div id="dialog-message" title="Процедура загрузки">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    Процедура загрузки
  </p>
  <p>
    <div class="container">
    <h2>Загрузить</h2>
    <hr>
    <!-- File Upload From -->
    <form name ="submit_file" action="fileUpload_hotcall" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">загрузить</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <br />
```

...

```
  $(function() {
    $('#btnsubhotcall').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Disable submit button
        $(this).prop('disabled',true);
        
        var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
        console.log('filename '+filename);
        if(filename.indexOf('zip') < 0 && filename.indexOf('rar') < 0){
            $('#alertMsg').text('Необходим файл с расширением *.zip или *.rar');
            $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled',false);
            
            throw "Bad extanshion";
            
        }
        
        var form = document.forms["submit_file"];
        var formData = new FormData(form);
            
        // Ajax call for file uploaling
        var ajaxReq = $.ajax({
            url : 'fileUpload_hotcall?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}',
            type : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            cache : false,
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            xhr: function(){
                //Get XmlHttpRequest object
                 var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr() ;
                
                //Set onprogress event handler 
                 xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event){
                    var perc = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
                    $('#progressBar').text(perc + '%');
                    $('#progressBar').css('width',perc + '%');
                 };
                 return xhr ;
            },
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                //Reset alert message and progress bar
                $('#alertMsg').text('');
                $('#progressBar').text('');
                $('#progressBar').css('width','0%');
              }
        });

        // Called on success of file upload
        ajaxReq.done(function(msg) {
            $('#alertMsg').text(msg);
            $('input[type=file]').val('');
            $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled',false);
        });
        
        // Called on failure of file upload
        ajaxReq.fail(function(jqXHR) {
            $('#alertMsg').text('Возникла ощибка\n'+jqXHR.responseText+'('+jqXHR.status+
                    ' - '+jqXHR.statusText+')');
            $('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled',false);
        });
    });
});
```

PetitController.java

```
  @PostMapping("/fileUpload_hotcall")
   public ResponseEntity<Object> fileUpload(@RequestParam(value = "_csrf", required = false) String csrf, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
         throws IOException, JAXBException {

      // Save file on system
      if (!file.getOriginalFilename().isEmpty()) {
          
         String pathStoreUploadedFile = Option.getDirectory("directory","directories.properties");
         
         File f = new File(pathStoreUploadedFile, file.getOriginalFilename());
         BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
         outputStream.write(file.getBytes());
         outputStream.flush();
         outputStream.close();
         
         List<Petit> pt = petitService.parseArchiveFile(f);
         
         for(Petit p : pt) petitService.addPetit(p);
         
      }else{
         return new ResponseEntity<>("Файл не загружен.",HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
      }
      
      return new ResponseEntity<>("Файл успешно загружен в базу.",HttpStatus.OK);
   }
```

Comment: Проблема в том что нет _csrf токена.

Comment: А это Spring Framework?

Comment: Да. Есть еще классы которые парсят.

Comment: по идее нужно добавить данный токен в ваш шаблон, ну или отключить защиту.

Comment: Можно поподробнее?

Comment: Попробуйте вставить в ваш шаблон `<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>`

Внутрь тэга `form`

Comment: Не помогает. Вставлял после строчки <form name ="submit_file" action="fileUpload_hotcall" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> и даже после </form>

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112739/discussion-between-bigtows-and-wq55).

Comment: Добавил функцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно добавить CSRF-токен в action, таким образом получится.

```
 <form name ="submit_file" 
       action="action="fileUpload_hotcall?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}"" 
       method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Но лучше всё-таки (из-за параметров безопасности) переместить эти данные в заголовок или в тело запроса, используя JavaScript, к примеру.

[Подробнее в пункте 18.5.4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.x/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-in-action)

Comment: Возвращаюсь к данному вопросу. Переместить эти данные в заголовок или в тело запроса, используя JavaScript - можно поподробнее, как можно это реализовать, чтобы обезопасить данные?